# fiddler intercept POST generated from R studio

Tags: r, rstudio, fiddler, httr

I am trying to intercept a POST request (generated by R httr package) via Fiddle but it seems to be not working. Any ideas?

Comment: What did you try exactly? Did you set up a proxy in R?

Comment: No I have not setup Proxy yet. Please guide me how to do that. Actually I am getting 406 response from an API and I want debug it.

Comment: Well, according to the [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) docs, [you need to set it up as a proxy](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureBrowsers). There are docs on [how to set up a proxy in Rstudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy)

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try and get back with my findings.

Comment: @MrFlick : Thank you for pointing me in right direction. It indeed worked well. You can add your note in answers and I will mark it as correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler works by acting as an HTTP proxy in order to intercept all your web traffic. If you want to use it with RStudio, you just need to make RStudio use that proxy.

By default, [the Fiddler proxy runs at Address: 127.0.0.1 Port: 8888](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureBrowsers).

Next, [you can tell Rstudio about the proxy by adding this lines to your Renviron file.](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy)

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888/
```