# How can I pass a line break through an API Patch or Post call in R to Microsoft Dataverse?

Tags: r, api, microsoft-dynamics, patch, carriage-return

I am trying to populate a table in Microsoft Dataverse using an API Patch call through R. The field in Dataverse is a multiline text field with a limit of 4,000 characters, but using a Patch call I can't seem to get text to break across lines. I have other entries in the table that break across lines where they had been brought in by using Access as the front end, which I'm trying to not have to use.

```
### This is where I create the multiline text
MPC.Comments$Comment = paste(paste("Meeting Date: ", month(Sys.Date()), "/", year(Sys.Date()), sep = ""),
                             paste("Plan Cost: $", round(MPC.Comments$plantot, 0), sep = ""),
                             paste("%PC Remain: ", round((round(MPC.Comments$plantot, 0) - round(MPC.Comments$acttot, 0) - round(MPC.Comments$comsub, 0))/round(MPC.Comments$plantot, 0)*100,1), "%", sep = ""),
                             paste("Date Next PM Gate: ", MPC.Comments$eventdate, sep = ""),
                             paste("Est. Monthly Spend: $", MPC.Comments$esttot, sep = ""),
                             paste("Status Update: ", MPC.Comments$MPCStatus, sep = ""),
                             paste("Action Items: ", MPC.Comments$MPCAction, sep = ""),
                             sep = " <\\r\\n>")

### This is where I try to push it to the database
if (nrow(MPC.Comments) > 0) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(MPC.Comments)) {
    ### Set POST parameters
    MPC.Comments.Temp = list(
      crfd0_projno = MPC.Comments$ProjNo[i],
      crfd0_fyp = MPC.Comments$FYP[i],
      crfd0_comment = MPC.Comments$Comment[i],
      statuscode = 1)
    
    POST("https://[REDACTED].crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/crfd0_mpccommentses",
         add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", API.AuthKey, sep = " ")),
         body = MPC.Comments.Temp,
         encode = "json",
         verbose())}}
```

No matter what special character I put in as my separator, it either comes through as nothing (if not escaped like `\n`) or as the physical string (if escaped like `\\n`). I have tried \n, \r\n, 
, <br>, and \u000a. Clearly there is a piece missing here that the data needs to be sent as something other than a string with a carriage return character. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: the separator (at least when dealing with JavaScript) is \n, the other fields are stored correctly? did you check with fiddler to see the actual request that has been sent?

Comment: What is the fiddler? I don't know how to go about viewing the actual request that was sent. If you have information on that, I'm happy to give it a try! It would solve a lot of problems!

Comment: it's a tool to inspect the http/https calls https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic, here an old question to use it in combination with RStudio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770799/fiddler-intercept-post-generated-from-r-studio